# How do I stop GCC stripping trailing newline from string literal in obj file?

Tags: linux, gcc, printf, newline, carriage-return

Working under Linux, i just met the following issue. (For sure, someone will give me the answer, but up to now,i didn't find any simple and clear answer :)

```
/*compile with gcc -o out.x hello.c*/

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World2\r\n");
    printf("Hello World3\r\n ");

 return 0;
}
```

Running the following code under Linux give two strings BUT the ending char are differents: the first output ends with 0x0d while the 2nd ends with 0x0d,0x0a.

This is something done by the compiler (GCC) as you can see in the obj file:

```
Contents of section .rodata:
 400610 01000200 48656c6c 6f20576f 726c6432  ....Hello World2
 400620 0d004865 6c6c6f20 576f726c 64330d0a  ..Hello World3..
 400630 2000                                  .
```

So, questions are:

- Why ?
- How can i avoid this kind of "optimization"(!?)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this optimization? The program’s behavior is completely identical (unless there’s a bug in the compiler); why do you care if the `\n` is in the string literal or inserted when the compiler changes `printf` to `puts`?

Comment: @DanielH: Well...not really the same.. eg.: in embedded world, where the output are send to a terminal (like screen or minicom). With this behavior, some traces can be "hidden" because of the lack of LF

Comment: @BFlash The exact same bytes will be written to `STDOUT` (this is guaranteed because only as-if optimizations are allowed). If you look at [the assembly code](https://godbolt.org/g/6i1pyw), it also replaces the first `printf` with `puts`, which adds a newline at the end. If this doesn’t happen, you have a major bug in your C library.

Comment: Thanks for pointing printf vs puts ! ... it makes sense ! (and you are right for the ... library bug :( )

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to avoid such a legal optimization. Your question lacks some practical motivation and context (maybe you have your own `printf`, but then you should name it differently...)

Comment: Please **edit your question** to *provide additional motivation and context*. As you see from the answers, your motivation is important, and I cannot guess it. I can't figure out why in embedded applications you don't want that (legal, and common) optimization to happen. Without motivation, **your question is unclear.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating formatted output at runtime takes time; the `printf` call is slow. GCC knows this, so [replaces](https://godbolt.org/g/5wb2r2) the first function with a call to [`puts`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts). Since `puts` automatically adds a `\n`, GCC needs to remove the `\n` from the string to compensate.

GCC does this because it considers `printf` a [*built-in*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). Because this has *no effect* on the bytes output or even on the number of calls to `write`; I strongly recommend leaving it as-is. If you *do* want to disable it, you [can pass](https://godbolt.org/g/J5eEHx) `-fno-builtin-printf`, but the only effect will be to slow down your code as it tries to format the string unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler to [ask GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) (using GCC7.2 on Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64) to emit assembler. So I compiled your program `bflash.c` with

```
gcc -fverbose-asm -O0 -S bflash.c -o bflash-O0.S
```

to get it without optimization, and with

```
gcc -fverbose-asm -O1 -S bflash.c -o bflash-O1.S
```

to get `-O1` optimization. Feel free to repeat the experiment with various [other optimization flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Even without optimization, the `bflash-O0.S` contains:

```
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World2\r"
.LC1:
    .string "Hello World3\r\n "
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
# bflash.c:5:     printf("Hello World2\r\n");
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi    #,
    call    puts@PLT    #
# bflash.c:6:     printf("Hello World3\r\n ");
    leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rdi    #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf@PLT  #
# bflash.c:8:  return 0;
    movl    $0, %eax    #, _4
# bflash.c:9: }
    popq    %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
```

As you see, the first `printf` has been optimized as a `puts`; and this is permitted by the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) ([as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)). BTW, the `bflash-01.S` contains similar code. Notice that the C11 standard has been specified with current optimization practices in mind (many members of the standardization committees are compiler implementors).

BTW [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) 5, invoked as `clang-5.0 -O1 -fverbose-asm -S bflash.c -o bflash-01clang.s`, performs the same kind of optimization.

> How can i avoid this kind of "optimization"(!?)

Follow [Daniel H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081370/841108) (and you might compile [with `-ffreestanding`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html), but I don't recommend that).

Or avoid using `printf` from the `<stdio.h>` and implement your own slower printing function. If you implement your own printing function, name it differently (since `printf` is defined in the C11 standard), and perhaps (if so wanted) write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to optimize it your way (and that plugin should better be some free software which [is GPL compatible](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugin-API.html#Plugin-API), read the [GCC runtime library exception](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1.en.html)).

The C language specification (study [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) defines a [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)), that is the *behavior* of your compiled program. It does not require any particular sequence of bytes to appear in the executable (which is probably not even mentioned in the standard). If you need such a property, find a different programming language, and give up all the important [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) GCC is trying hard to do for you. Optimizations are what is making [writing a C compiler difficult](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065) (if you want a non-optimizing compiler, use something else than GCC, but accept to lose perhaps a factor of three or more in performance, w.r.t. code compiled with `gcc -O2`).

Comment: On my system (embedded), puts is from the standard library as printf is rewritten...which lead to this kind of problem. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Both `puts` and `printf` are standardized in C11. So the compiler is right in performing such an optimization.