# How can I know where function ends in memory(get the address)- c/c++

Tags: c, memory

I'm looking for a simple way to find function ending in memory. I'm working on a project that will find problems on run time in other code, such as: code injection, viruses and so fourth. My program will run with the code that is going to be checked on run time, so that I will have access to memory. I don't have access to the source code itself. I would like to examine only specific functions from it. I need to know where functions start and end in stack. I'm working with windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? What is the *real* problem you want to solve? Please [read about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and think about how this question might be one.

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't have a legitimate need to do it.

Comment: what about disassembling with mixed symbols ?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it, give a lot more details (in what program, what compiler, what operating system, what optimization options, what kind of code) and give *motivation* and *context*. Without it, your question has no sense.

Comment: C is usually compiled, but there are also [interpreters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/584714/2564301). A hypothetical routine to locate the "end of a function"  would thus return the line of text containing its closing `}`.

Comment: Sorry, I will rephrase my question.

Comment: How much time (in years) do you have for your project? Are you working alone? What is the size of your team? Are you aware that your project is very ambitious (and any program doing well what you wish needs to be very big: millions of lines of source code). Malware software is not naive! So there is *no simple way* to get what you want.

Comment: What will happen if you fail your (incredibly ambitious) project? This is a question to ask yourself!

Answer (score 9):

In general, you cannot find where the function is ending in memory, because the compiler could have [optimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion), cloned or removed that function, split it in different parts, etc. That function could be some [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) mostly implemented in the kernel, or some function in an external [shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) ("outside" of your program's [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable))... For the C11 standard (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) point of view, your question has no sense. That standard defines the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of the language, i.e. properties on the behavior of the produced program. See also explanations in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081361/841108) answer.

<sup>On some computers ([Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture)) the code would stay in a different memory, so there is no point in asking where that function starts or ends.</sup>

If you restrict your question to a particular C *implementation* (that is a specific [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) with particular optimization settings, for a specific [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) you might (in *some* cases,  not in all of them) be able to find the "end of a function" (but that won't be simple, and won't be failproof). For example, you could post-process the assembler code and/or the [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) produced by the compiler, inspect the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable and its symbol table, examine [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information, etc...

Your question smells a lot like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), so you should motivate it, whith *a lot more* explanation and context.

> I need to know where functions start and end in stack.

Functions don't sit on the stack, but mostly in the [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) of your executable (or library). What is on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is a sequence of call frames. The organization of the call frames is specific to your ABI. Some compiler [options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) (e.g. `-fomit-frame-pointer`) would make difficult to explore the call stack (without access to the source code and help from the compiler).

> I don't have access to the source code itself. I would like to examine only specific functions from it.

Your problem is still ill-defined, probably [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem), much more complex than what you believe (since related to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)), and there is considerable literature related to it (read about [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler), [static code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), [anti-virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivirus_software) & [malware analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware_analysis)). I recommend spending several months or years learning more about compilers (start with the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)), [linkers](http://iecc.com/linkers/), instruction set architecture, ABIs. Then look into several proceedings of conferences related to ACM [SIGPLAN](http://www.sigplan.org/) etc. On a practical side, study the assembler code generated by compilers (e.g. use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with `gcc -O2 -S -fverbose-asm`....); the CppCon 2017 talk: Matt Godbolt [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) is a nice introduction.

> I'm working on a project that will find problems on run time in other code, such as: code injection, viruses and so fourth.

I hope you can dedicate several years of full time work to your ambitious project. It probably is much more difficult than what you thought, because optimizing compilers are [much more complex](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065) than what you believe (and [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) software uses various complex tricks to hide itself from inspection). [Malware research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware_research) is really difficult, but interesting.

Comment: Agree with all of this very good answer aside from the Harvard architecture part.  That architecture does not present any more or less applicability to OP's question even if its function addresses are not comparable to object ones.  It does present perhaps additional challenges.